# how i can return the header content from webapi to AngularJS $http service

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, angularjs-1.6

I want to return the content headers from webapi as

```
httpResponseMessage.Content = new ByteArrayContent(bytes.ToArray());
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("x-filename", fileName);
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("attachment");
httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName = fileName;
```

and i want to return this content headers to angularjs $http service as

```
$http.get(...).then(function(response){..})
```

i am using AngularJS 1.6, but previous in AngularJS 1.3, it is working fine , by using 
`$http.get(...).success`
but as now it is AngularJS 1.6, it is not working, i cannot work with angularjs 1.3 in my project as it is already 1.6 is there, so please help me, how to get the content header data from webapi to angularjs $http service

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it a cross-domain request? If yes, have you tried exposing custom headers?

httpResponseMessage.Content.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "x-filename");